# vector<string> does not clear memory after out of scope

Tags: c++, linux, string, memory, vector

i've encountered the following problem, and i'm not really sure whether i am wrong or its a really weird bug. I fill a huge array of strings and want it to be cleared at a certain point. Here's a minimal example

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h> //sleep
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    {
        std::vector<std::string> strvec;
        for(long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){
            std::string out = "This is gonna be a long string just to fill up the memory used by this fucking pthread\n";
            strvec.push_back(out);
        }
        std::cout << "finished loading 1st\n";
        sleep(10); // to monitor any changes    
    }
    std::cout << "out of scope\n";
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

My Problem is, if i monitor memory usage with 'top', the memory usage decreases just by a very small amount (i think its probably the vector overhead), but the most seems not freed. How comes? I tested the same scenario with 'long long', but here everything went right.

The std::vector reference states, that, if the contained values are no pointers, the destructors are invoked. Seems not true for string though...

I appreciate every answer.

(for convenience: i'm using debian linux 64Bit with g++ 4.7.2)

EDIT: thanks for the answers so far.

by now i have profiled heap usage with vagrind massif, and (yeah, actually as expected) it gets properly freed at the point it should. But why do i in fact see a change in usage with a huge integer, but not with the strings (also whithin top)?

I need to be a little considerable about that, because i need to be able to free my memory  at certain times for a multithreaded server application, which will probably run several weeks or more without being restarted. When do i actually know when the C++ memory manager decides to give some mem back to the OS?

Comment: Try debugging with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) it will tell you whether memory is free or not, and would probably be more helpful than `top`.

Comment: What is it with people's insistence that memory be wasted? Free memory does *nothing* -- it's no better than memory that's not in the computer at all. Only memory that's *in use* does any good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a specific of using the `top` command, not of the `std::vector`. The issue is that the memory freed by data structures is not released back to the operating system, the level at which the `top` command monitors memory usage. The memory the OS has given your program remains with your program until the memory manager of C++ decides that it's time to free some memory back to the operating system.

The reason for this is that allocating memory from the operating system is relatively expensive, and it needs to be done in relatively large chunks. The memory manager of the C++ runtime library obtains memory from the OS "wholesale", and then parcels it out to the parts of your program as needed.

If you would like to verify that the memory does indeed get reclaimed, use a tool that monitors memory usage at a lower level, such as [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Even if you free the memory properly, the standard library doesn't necessary free the memory back to the OS.

So for example, when you first allocate all of the memory, the library allocates a bunch of virtual memory address space from the OS (likely with `mmap(2)`) and doles it out.  But when you're done with that memory, it hangs onto the virtual address space under the assumption that you might want that memory back later, so it doesn't call `munmap(2)` to unmap the virtual address space.

Hence, even though all of the memory has been properly freed from your program's perspective, all the OS sees is that you allocated a bunch of virtual memory but then never freed it.  That's why `top(1)` reports your memory usage as not decreasing, but it's nothing to be concerned about.  When your program needs memory again, it'll allocate it from the virtual address space which you already have, so you won't see your apparent memory usage increase until all of that memory has been used up.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers the memory is still available to your process and not freed outside of it until the program quits. If you want an allocator that will do this, you can check out using jemalloc which can free it back to the OS and is very useful in scalable multi threaded apps like facebook but as with anything there are other costs.