# Memory release of boost::shared_ptr of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector, stl

I'm trying to release the memory of a `boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > >` using the following code:

```
vec->clear();
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > (*vec).swap(*vec);
```

But for some reason it isn't working. I checked with *htop* command and the memory used is the same as I've never released the object.

Then I tried to release each vector separately like:

```
for (auto it1 : *vec) 
{
    for (auto it2 : it1)
    {
        it2.clear();
        std::vector<int>(it2).swap(it2);
    }
    it1.clear();
    std::vector<int>(it1).swap(it1);
}
```

But still consumes the same amount of memory.

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe it has to do with the shared_ptr because I've released vectors without pointers before and it worked.

**Update**

The shared_ptr won't get out of scope since is a class member of an object that remains in execution in a sleeping thread.

Comment: `vec.release()` should destroy everything. But whatever you do, the memory will probably be released to the process's heap, not back to the OS (although the details are platform dependent). You'll need deeper magic if you really want that level of control.

Comment: Don't use OS tools to determine what the `C++` heap manager is doing internally.

Comment: What is the type of `vec`? It can't be `shared_ptr<...>` because then your code wouldn't compile. And you might want to consider Boost.MultiArray instead of a vector of vector of vectors.

Comment: what is the goal of the pattern `var.clear(); type(var).swap(var);` ?

Comment: @Johan clear will call the destructor of every object in the vector, and swap will shrink the vector size to 0 (since there aren't more objects)

Comment: `I've released vectors without pointers before and it worked` You are not guaranteed that this works. It is actually the compiler's heap manager that controls the interaction between your application's usage of heap memory and the OS. Maybe a simple reason is that the heap manager realizes you may allocate the memory again, therefore all it needs to do is adjust a couple of internal pointers in its data structures instead of making an expensive call to the OS to deallocate (and then allocate again).

Comment: @Jcao02 [I do not think that it is guaranteed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap). I even think that to keep iterator valid, you cannot free the buffer. [shrink_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) seems a lot more suited for this purpose.

Comment: @Praetorian yes it is... is boost::shared_ptr<vector...>, And it works. I'm using GCC 4.7

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what should I use to determine this?

Comment: @Jcao02 How is this copy construction supposed to work if `vec` is a `shared_ptr`? `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >(vec)` - note that you have an extra `>` in the example above.

Comment: But shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request, so it could be ignore, isn't it? @Johan

Comment: @Praetorian my mistake, it is using the value of the smart pointer (*vec)

Comment: @Jcao02 - This may sound flippant, but use "common sense". You know that the code doesn't leak memory, right? So trust your compiler's heap manager to control the situation.  The heap manager will know at an efficient point in time when to actually call on the OS to deallocate the memory.  If you really and truly had a memory leak, then yes, the OS tools will *eventually* show that something is wrong. But you can't use those tools to microanalyze your C++'s heap manager's operations.

Comment: @Jcao02 Sorry, trying to understand better your `clear/build/swap` pattern I see that it does work. I said something stupid regarding iterator because indeed they will be conserved in the swapped vector that will be destruct. But it seems a bit too overkill for me.

Comment: @Jcao02 Ok, now try printing out `vec->capacity()` before and after the `swap`

Comment: @Praetorian you mean with the first version of calling clear with *vec*, or is it necessary to do it with all the internal vectors?

Comment: @Jcao02 Just add it to your existing code as shown above. It'll be hard for the internal vectors to contain anything if `vec->capacity() == 0` after the `swap` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector>>` and you want to delete it:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> ptr = ...;
ptr.reset();
```

If you have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` and you want to empty it:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> vec = ...;
vec.clear();
```

If you have a `std::vector<T>` and you want the `vec.capacity() == vec.size()`:

```
std::vector<T> vec = ...;
vec.shrink_to_fit(); // or: std::vector<T>(vec).swap(vec);
```

If you are concerned that **`htop`** doesn't show a reduced amount of allocated memory to the process, then let's just mark this as a duplicate of this post: [vector<string> does not clear memory after out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871970/vectorstring-does-not-clear-memory-after-out-of-scope)

Comment: does reset assure the release of the memory of every vector?

Comment: If you call `ptr.reset()` when `ptr.use_count() == 1` and `ptr.get() != NULL`, then the destructor will be called on the contained `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: @Jcao02: Is your question actually: _Does std::vector<std::vector<int>>'s destructor work correctly?_

Comment: Nope,  i thought maybe I had to do something special due the pointers and multiple vectors inside the pointers